Flutter IOS app running issue in Emulator
I have Flutter Android and IOS app. The Android app runs fine. When I run the IOS app in the Emulator, I am getting the following errors.
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: nominal type descriptor for RevenueCat.PresentedOfferingContext

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: RevenueCat.Package.__allocating_init(identifier: Swift.String, packageType: RevenueCat.PackageType, storeProduct: RevenueCat.StoreProduct, presentedOfferingContext: RevenueCat.PresentedOfferingContext) -> RevenueCat.Package

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: direct field offset for RevenueCat.Package.presentedOfferingContext : RevenueCat.PresentedOfferingContext

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: RevenueCat.Offering.metadata.getter : [Swift.String : Any]

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: RevenueCat.Offerings.currentOffering(forPlacement: Swift.String) -> RevenueCat.Offering?

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

Thank you
